# Setting an instance variable inside of module

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to create a module that sets and instance variable called `@evaluator` on it's included class. I then want to access that variable in `method_missing` of the included class:

```
module ObjectInquiry
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do

      def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
        @evaluator.call
      end
      def self.inquiry(method_name = nil, &block)
        @evaluator = block if block_given?
      end
    end
  end
end

class Post
  include ObjectInquiry

  inquiry do
    true
  end
end
```

If I then do:

```
Post.new.awesome?
```

I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'call' for nil:NilClass`. I'm guessing this is because I'm improperly setting `evaluator` or something. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: The `@evaluator` you set is on class level, the `@evaluator` you try to read is on instance level. The class and the instance are two different objects and therefore the two `@evaluator` are different variables.

Comment: When you call the class method `inquiry` you set the class instance variable `@evaluator`. When you call `method_missing` you send `call` to the uniititalized instance variable with the same name. The two variables are as different as `@dog` and `@cat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your module structure is a bit unidiomatic. To define instance methods, we can simply put a `def` inside the module. To define class methods, one would typically define a nested module `ClassMethods` and call `base.extend` in the include hook. It saves a level of indentation - this doesn't seem like much but it can add up to quite awkward code. The following modules are equivalent:

```
module A
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      def instance_method
        puts 'Hello from instance A!'
      end

      def self.class_method
        puts 'Hello from class A!'
      end

      foo() # code evaluated in class body
    end
  end
end

module B
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      foo()
    end

    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  def instance_method
    puts 'Hello from instance B!'
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def class_method
      puts 'Hello from class B!'
    end
  end
end
```

If you're using Rails or `require 'active_support/concern'` you can even `extend ActiveSupport::Concern` to reduce the amount of boilerplate code:

```
module C
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    foo()
  end

  def instance_method
    puts 'Hello from instance B!'
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def class_method
      puts 'Hello from class B!'
    end
  end
end
```

The next thing you need to understand is the difference between instance variables and *class instance variables*. For example this is how to set an instance variable and then retrieve it *in context of the instance*

```
class C
  def set_value
    @x = 123
  end

  def get_value
    @x
  end
end
```

And this is how to set a class instance variable and then retrieve it *in context of the instance*. If you think of class `D` as instance of the class `Class`, then the term "class instance variable" makes kind of sense. I think the simplest way to access a class instance variable from an instance of the class is to define an attr_accessor in the class' Eigenclass.

```
class D
  class << self
    attr_accessor :x
  end

  def self.set_value
    self.x = 123          # self refers to the class, we need to use self.x
  end

  def get_value
    self.class.x          # self refers to the instance, we need to use self.class.x
  end
end
```

All of these hints result in the following code:

```
module ObjectInquiry
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      class << self
        attr_accessor :evaluator
      end
    end

    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    self.class.evaluator.call
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def inquiry(method_name = nil, &block)
      self.evaluator = block if block_given?
    end
  end
end
```

Testing:

```
class Post
  include ObjectInquiry

  inquiry do
    true
  end
end

Post.new.flabbergasted?
#=> true
```